# Non-numeric argument to binary operator while drawing curve of a function

Tags: r, graph, curve

For the following R-Code, I am getting error `Error in (k - 3) * h1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` while executing last code line that draws its curve. What is the possible solution?

```
k = 4
g4 = function(theta) {
    h1 = function(x) { dchisq(x,df=k+1,ncp=theta)/x } 
    h4 = function(x) { dchisq(x,df=k+3,ncp=theta)/x }
    (k-1) * integrate((1-(k-3) * h1)^2, 0, k-3)$value + 
        theta * (2 * integrate((1-(k-3) * h1), 0, k-3)$value - 
        integrate((1-(k-3) * h4)^2, 0, k-3)$value)
}
RPS = function(theta) { sapply(theta,g4) }
curve(RPS, from=0, to=20, lwd=2, lty=1, xlab="theta", ylab="AQR", ylim=c(0,8))
```

While following code works well

```
  k = 4
 g3 = function(theta){
 h1 = function(x) { dchisq(x,df=k+1,ncp=theta)/x }
 h2 = function(x){ dchisq(x,df=k+1,ncp=theta)/(x^2) }
 h3 = function(x){ dchisq(x,df=k+3,ncp=theta)/(x^2) }
 k+(theta*(k-3)*(k+1)*integrate(h3,0,Inf)$value)-(k-1)*(k-3)*(2*integrate(h1,0,Inf)$value-(k-3)*integrate(h2,0,Inf)$value)
}
 RJS=function(theta){ sapply(theta,g3) }
 curve(RJS, from=0, to=20, lwd=2, lty=1, xlab="theta", ylab="AQR", ylim=c(0,8))
```

and I get required curve but not for first code.

Comment: `h1` is defined as a function, not a numeric.  You are not using it correctly in `integrate((1-(k-3)*h1)^2,0,k-3)`

Comment: I am integrating its squared function over a region, so it must return a numeric value. But it gives an error.

Comment: How can I get rid of these errors? Any hint.

Comment: As Richard said, you need to define x before you get to the last line of your `g4` function. What is the variable on which `h1` and `h4` are supposed to operate? Is it `k`?

Comment: I have given a demo code where I am not passing anything yet I am getting required curve.